# Unable to connect Django app to an external PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, django, macos, postgresql, ubuntu

**Short Description**
I am having a number of issues trying to connect a Django app (currently setup as SQLite3) to a newly created PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu Server.

**The Question(s)**
Can anyone share their success in doing this?  Is there a good step-by-step tutorial on doing this?  Or at least useful pointers on how to debug this?

**Steps So Far (Background information)**
**1)** I have installed PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu Server following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) tutorial.  Note that this produced Zero errors.
**2)** I configured my Django settings.py as seen below

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', 
    'NAME': 'mytestdb',                   
    'USER': 'mux_user',                    
    'PASSWORD': 'mux',                  
    'HOST': '192.168.1.111',                      
    'PORT': '',                  
    }
}
```

**3)** Ran Django's 'syncdb'.  This generated the following error.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg module: No module named psycopg

**4)** Attempted to install psycopg with PIP, easy_install, and with the setup.py.  All had the same failure of not being able to find the pg_config.

**5)** Google told me that I needed to install libpq-dev and python-dev in-order to compile the psycopg package.  This is where I have lost most of my confidence in understanding what I am doing.  I understand that these 2 packages are to allow me to compile python source, but is it *really* necessary to do this?

**System Information**
***Client:***
OS: OS X Snow Leopard-10.6.6
Django: Version 1.2.5
Python: 2.7 (running virtualenv)

***Soon to be client***
OS: Windows XP / 7
Running an bundled executable of the python environment above

***Server:***
OS: Ubuntu 10.10 (server, no gui)
PostgreSQL: 8.4 (that's what apt-get install downloaded)

**Update**
I did find in the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/install/) where it talks about needing to install psycopg.  I suppose the question moves from do I really need this, to what is the best way to install psycopg on my clients.

**Update 5-13-2011: 9:20AM**
After speaking with a colleague, I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629368) SO question addresses most of my issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues I ran into were centered around using a 32bit install of Python (required by wxPython 2.8 on Snow Leopard).  Please see my answer on this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629368).

@mu is too short: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Python guy but you do need the PostgreSQL libraries installed as the Python interface to PostgreSQL (psycopg) is just a Python layer on top of the PostgreSQL C libraries. So, no PostgreSQL development libraries means there's nothing to wrap in Python and no way to talk to PostgreSQL from Python.

Comment: This is exactly why I started to install psycopg.  However, I do not know if this is required when using Django.  Judging by my errors, I would say yes, but I could not find anywhere in the Django documentation about needing this module.  Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Adam: I don't think Django itself needs psycopg or any of its supporting libraries but your application needs to talk to PostgreSQL so your application needs psycopg and friends.

Comment: @Adam: I think `brew install postgresql` should get you everything you need if you're using Homebrew. That'll give you the server as well as the libraries but that shouldn't be a big deal as the server won't run unless you ask it to.

Comment: @mu: That's exactly what I have done.  However, now I am having troubling installing Postgres with homebrew :|  I just can't win.

Comment: @mu:  I will look into Cinderalla.  Thanks for the tip.  Regarding the "having trouble installing PostreSQL", I would rather start up a new question once I have more intelligent things to say than 'HELP!' :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your pg_config into your path, first locate this file on your machine, then run something similar to:

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin
    pip install psycopg2
```

If you do not have postgres installed on your client machine, then you should be able to install with macports:

```
    sudo port install postgresql90
```

Comment: As I pointed out in my question, I do not have pg_config on my machine.  I am not at a point where I can look this up, so do you know if I can install what I need with homebrew?