# Install PostgreSQL for Django on Maverick OS Mac

Tags: django

does anyone know of an installation tutorial for setting up PostgreSQL for Django. I am using virtualenvwrapper and all that stuff. I can't seem to get it to work with what I have tried so far.

Comment: I install all my stuff using mac ports: http://www.macports.org

Comment: Or brew http://brew.sh/ the newest and greatest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629368/installing-psycopg2-into-virtualenv-when-postgresql-is-not-installed-on-developm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/panuta/1852087

This is a complete list of commands on OS X (working on Mountain Lion, should be okay in Mavericks) to install Postgresql and Django as well as Virtualenvwrapper. The setup for is the same as other OS.