# Psycopg2 pycharm install error

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, pycharm, psycopg2

I have installed psycopg2 on the command line and the installation has worked. However in pycharm when I import it I get told I need to install it. Then when I try install it I get the following error.

[image: The error I get when I try install the psycopg2 package]

Why does Pycharm not recognise that it is already installed?
How would you recommend I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Try again with `sudo`

Comment: @GeorgeD Where  should I use the Sudo?

Comment: @GeorgeD when I use Sudo -h in Default Settings> Project interpreter > + > (choose psycopg2 and in options add sudo -h) it works. it says "Packages installed successfully: Installed packages: 'psycopg2'" but the package does not show as imported!

Comment: have a look at these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629368 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866695/