# Install libpq-dev on Mac OS X

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to run Django with a Postgresql backend on my local Mac OS X.  I've installed Django using pip:

```
sudo pip install Django
```

I've installed Postgresql with one of the binary installers [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/).

But when I try to install psycopg2 I get an error (pasted below) that it can't find pg_config.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python) it seems like I should install `libpq-dev` but I'm not sure how.

I've tried installing `libpqxx` with MacPorts, but that hasn't done anything.

How do I get libpg-dev installed?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

```
henrietta:~ $ pip install psycopg2
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz (719Kb): 719Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2
    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info

writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: pg_config executable not found.



Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH

or specify the full executable path with the option:



    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...



or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/thomas/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 33):

For OSX 10.9.2 Mavericks, this is what worked for me. Try installing postgres with brew first:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Then install pg

```
gem install pg
```

Comment: I had to do `brew link postgresql@9.4 --force` so that the gem could find the `pg_config` binary

Answer (score 15):

So I ended up following the advice here:

http://blog.jonypawks.net/2008/06/20/installing-psycopg2-on-os-x/

Turns out I did have `pg-config` installed, but I had to dig around to find it a bit.  Once I included that in the path, everything worked swimmingly.  Here's the snippet from that link:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgresPlus/8.3/bin/ sudo easy_install psycopg2
```

I used `pip` instead of `easy_install` and my PostgreSQL installation directory was slightly different, but that's the gist.

Comment: This worked A-OK for me. OSX Maverick with Postgres.app 9.2.2.0: PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin pip install psycopg2

Comment: update for OSX Mav with Postgres.app 9.3.2.0 RC2 `sudo PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Can't find `/bin` either. What is that directory supposed to have?

Comment: Update for OSX Mav with Postgres 9.3
`PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/ pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 4):

Just install postgres from source. I'm doing that on Mac OS X. It's as easy as:

```
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

Of course you may need extra steps like autostarting, or setting configure options, but I belive this is still most painless way of setting up on Mac OS X.

And if you for some reason want to avoid installing from source, you should look for a binary version of psycopg2, e.g. here: http://www.initd.org/psycopg/download/

```
sudo port install py27-psycopg2
```

Answer (score 2):

In postgress.app on mavericks the file `pg_config` is in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/` so i fixed the problem in this way:

```
sudo PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/ pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks a ton!  To get this working on El Capitan, you need to use a slightly different path.  `sudo PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/ pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 0):

Using macports, this worked for me:

```
sudo port install postgresql96
sudo port select --set postgresql postgresql96
```

I believe this installs all the postgres client tools and libs, while macports has a separate port for installing the server, i.e. `postgresql96-server`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to install `psycopg2` to run on a mac for Django or Flask etc. then use:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

From the docs https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html