# Psycopg2 Python SSL Support is not compiled in

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, ssl, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to my postgres database using psycopg2 with sslmode='required' param; however, I get the following error

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in
```

Heres a couple details about my system

- Mac OS X El Capitan
- Python 2.7
- Installed psycopg2 via pip
- Installed python via homebrew

Here is what I tried to do to fix the problem

- `brew uninstall python`
- `which python` still shows python living in `/usr/local/bin/python`, tried to uninstall this but couldnt. And heard that this is the python that the OS uses and should not be uninstalled anyways
- `brew install python --with-brewed-openssl --build-from-source`
- `pip uninstall psycopg2`
- `pip install psycopg2`

After doing all of this, the exception still happens. I am running this python script via `#!/usr/bin/env python` Not sure if it matters, but that is a different directory than the one that `which python` shows

Comment: Does your database have the required ssl support compiled in?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the `pip install psycopg2` command? Also, which version of psycopg have you installed (visible with `pip list`)?

Comment: @andreas-hofmann `pip install psycopg2` shows `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. When I run `pip list` I get `psycopg2 (2.6.1)`

Comment: Okay, so the version I guessed in my answer matches. I wanted to see whether there were any warnings or the like while the module was being built, but this should not matter. I still think you need to install libpq with SSL support...

Comment: How did you install your postgres server?

Answer (score 7):

Since you're installing via pip, you should be using the most recent version of psycopg2 (2.6.1).
After a little digging through the code, it seems that the exception is being thrown in connection_int.c, which directly calls the postgresql-c-libraries to set up the db-connection. The call happens like so:

```
self->pgconn = pgconn = PQconnectStart(self->dsn);

Dprintf("conn_connect: new postgresql connection at %p", pgconn);

if (pgconn == NULL)
{
    Dprintf("conn_connect: PQconnectStart(%s) FAILED", self->dsn);
    PyErr_SetString(OperationalError, "PQconnectStart() failed");
    return -1;
}
else if (PQstatus(pgconn) == CONNECTION_BAD)
{
    Dprintf("conn_connect: PQconnectdb(%s) returned BAD", self->dsn);
    PyErr_SetString(OperationalError, PQerrorMessage(pgconn));
    return -1;
}
```

The keywords which were specified in your connect statement to psycopg2.connect() are being handled to that function and errors are returned as OperationalError exception.

The error is actually being generated directly in the postgresql-lib - you may want to check which version you are using, how it was built and, if possible, upgrade it to a version with SSL support or rebuilt it from source with SSL enabled.

The postgresql-docs also state that missing SSL support will raise an error, if the sslmode is set to **require**, **verify-ca** or **verify-full**. See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) under `sslmode` for reference.

The [postgres-website](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) lists several ways to install postgres from binary packages, so you might choose one which suits your needs. I'm not familiar with OSX, so I don't have a recommendation what's best.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132274/install-libpq-dev-on-mac-os-x) question may also be helpful.

You also need to reinstall the psycopg2-module, be sure to use the newly installed lib when rebuilding it. Refer to the linked question (in short, you will need to place the path to `pg_config` which is included in your new installation to $PATH when running `pip install psycopg2`).

Answer (score 6):

I had this same error, which turned out to be because I was using the Anaconda version of psycopg2. To fix it, I had adapt [VictorF's solution from here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/conda/Fqv93VKQXAc/A6APgLAPAQAJ) and run:

```
conda uninstall psycopg2
sudo ln -s /Users/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /Users/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
pip install psycopg2
```

Then when you run `conda list` you'll see psycopg2 installed with `<pip>` in the far right column. After that, I just restarted Python and everything worked.

Answer (score 5):

The error you are receiving is caused by a problem with Postgres itself, and not `psycopg2`.

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in
```

The above indicates that the version of Postgres that `psycopg2` is built against does not have SSL support compiled in. When you attempt to connect to the running Posgres server with `ssl=require` it throws this error.

You don't mention how you installed Postgres but since you are using Homebrew for other things, I recommend you also install Postgres the same way:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install postgresql
```

The [formula for postgresql](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb) shows that it depends on `openssl` and compiles with the `--with-openssl` flag set. It will also install the neccessary `libpq` headers. You may need to reinstall `psycopg2` after this step to ensure it picks up the correct libraries/version.

Interestingly, there is a [bug listed against conda](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1517) which lists the same error that you report occurring when the conda version of `psycopg2` — linked on a system with Homebrew postgres — was installed on a system without, suggesting missing SSL libraries can also trigger this.

I would suggest uninstalling any existing Postgres versions (including any installed via Homebrew) before reinstalling to minimise the risk of the wrong one being used.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the error message looks to be coming from Postgres.  You can verify this by typing: `psql sslmode=require`  if it gives you a pgsql terminal then ssl works with postgres, if it errors then it doesn't

Try and remove postgres and reinstall with openssl support:

```
brew uninstall postgres
brew update
brew install postgres --with-openssl
```

Alternatively, and this is the way I'd suggest, there is a one click installer at http://postgresapp.com that might also make it easier to get it installed.  Follow the instructions on the site to get it installed correctly.

When I did it on Yosemite it installed at ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres93/var

You'll also want to create a certificate (this could also be where the error is coming from) either from a registrar if this is going to be public facing in the slightest or self signed if it's for a dev/test environment.

```
openssl req -new -text -out server.req
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out server.key
rm privkey.pem
openssl req -x509 -in server.req -text -key server.key -out server.crt
chmod og-rwx server.key
```

Navigate to your config directory, by default it is: ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres93/var

Enable ssl support:

```
vim postgresql.conf
# change this:
# ssl = on
# to this:
ssl = on
```

Restart the app and then check ssl with `psql "sslmode=require"`

If that works then try it through your Python code.  If it works with the code above, but not Python then it's definitely a Python code problem that needs to be worked through.

Answer (score 1):

As I can not comment:
Adding to Brideau's answer that this only worked for me after changing my version of Postgres.

```
brew uninstall postgres
brew update
brew install postgres --with-openssl
```

Then run the code provided by Brideau and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using v2.6.1 or v2.6.2 of psycopg2 (like me), the answer was a simple upgrade to v2.7. Reading the [release notes](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/news.html) for psycopg2, there was a minor fix for SSL albeit it doesn't look particularly relevant.

My setup was as follows:

- Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
- psycopg2 2.6.2 installed via pip
- PostgreSQL installed via Enterprise DB Installer

Running `pip uninstall psycopg2` followed by `pip install psycopg2` resolved matters.

Answer (score -4):

Try to install `psycopg2` from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php)

```
 sudo port install py27-psycopg2
```