# SSL connection to Redshift using Psycopg2

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a AWS Redshift server via SSL. I am using psycopg2 library in python to establish the connection and used `sslmode='require'` as a parameter in the connect line. Unfortunately i got this error:

```
sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in
```

I read many other similar cases for PostgreSQL which mention the problem exists with the PostgeSQL version, but i didn't find any solutions for Redshift using Psycopg2. Do i need to install any specific SSL certificate for Redshift? If yes, how do i do it with Psycopg2? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489939/101266

> had this same error, which turned out to be because I was using the Anaconda version of psycopg2. To fix it, I had adapt VictorF's solution from here and run:

```
conda uninstall psycopg2
sudo ln -s /Users/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /Users/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your cluster enabled for SSL connections? Your URL itself will have the SSL info. and you can use the same in your code.