# Pyscopg2 SSL Anaconda Support not compiled in

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl, anaconda, psycopg2

I am having the following issue with psycopg2.  I am connect to a remote postgres server that is running 9.4.5.

I get the following error when I use SSLmode:required

> OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) sslmode value "require" >invalid when SSL support is not compiled in

I am running Anaconda fully updated with psycopg2.  I have deleted and reinstall Anaconda, removed and re-installed pip install psycopg2. Followed the brew install / brew uninstall suggested.

I have looked into the following threads from stack ==> 
[Psycopg2 Python SSL Support is not compiled in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684376/psycopg2-python-ssl-support-is-not-compiled-in)
as well as many other resources on the internet without success.

If anyone can help me out that would be fantastic - I feel like I have maxed out on my own abiliti to resolve this - hence I am posting up on Stack!  Thanks

Comment: Do you observe this problem with the package in the conda-forge channel? `conda install -c conda-forge psycopg2=2.6.2`

Comment: @cel I haven't tried the conda-forge channel.  What is that?  Will try...

Comment: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/community-conda-forge

Comment: @cel are the conda-forge recipes pretty stable then?  I will give this a try first thing tomorrow.  Appreciate the direction - hope i solves the problem.

Comment: in my experience they're of very high quality, sometimes even better than the current ones in the default channels.

Comment: @cel thanks - worked like a charm.  It does have some more printed outputs but I can get access to the db, so I am happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cel resolved this for me in the comment thread above.

After working through all the different options it looks like using the

> conda install -c conda-forge psycopg2=2.6.2
>   solution is the workaround that indeed worked for me.

If anyone has other resolutions let me know and I will add them here. I hope noone has the same issues.