# Using Cloudbees Jenkins to test Django/Postgres deployments

Tags: django, postgresql, jenkins, cloudbees

I'm trying to implement automatic testing for a Django project with a Postgres database, but my builds are failing when installing psycopg2 because `pg_config` cannot be found with an error message that can be read [here](http://pastebin.com/JGFwN43p).  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5450183/807674), it's because `libpq-dev` and `python-dev` may not be installed. One solution that will not work for me is using an alternative DB for testing because I have some core code that depends on Postgres-specific features. I'm wondering, has anybody been able to get Django with Postgres up and running on Cloudbees' Jenkins, and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: what was your workaround? do you mind sharing?

Comment: @user805981 At this point, I don't remember if I solved the problem at all

Answer (score 2):

You should run python with http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Python+Builds, so that you can select the exact runtime version to be used and get a virtualenv set, where setting custom python environment is easier

Comment: I like the sound of that, but I've moved on to another setup, so I don't want to accept without knowing whether it works in my case.  But I may be circling back to Cloudbees, and I'll try this if I do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this, if you're using python 3, you need to

```
apt-get install python3-dev
```