# latest version of psycopg2 on aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, psycopg2

I am trying to get the latest version of psycopg2 on my aws instance. I noticed that the latest version was 2.4.6 but I could only get 2.0.14 on aws. Is there a way to get the latest version? There are some features I need that are not supported in the earlier versions.

Answer (score 8):

Working answer as of November 2022:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel python3-devel
pip install wheel
pip install psycopg2
```

If you are still using Python 2 then use `python-devel` instead of `python3-devel`.

The `pip install wheel` is not strictly necessary, but `psycopg2` prefers it and it wasn't installed yet in my environment.

Comment: hero!!! This is the real answer

Answer (score 7):

## This works for me in Amazon aws-cli/1.9.11 Python/2.7.10 Linux/4.1.10 and Ubuntu 14

*If pip not installed in your **Amazon AWS** machine type:*

**$ sudo yum install python-pip**

and then type below commands:

**$ sudo yum update**

**$ sudo yum install libpq-dev python-dev**

**$ sudo pip install psycopg2**

*Then you will get message like below :*

You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 372kB 1.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.6.1

---

*If pip not installed in your  **Ubuntu** machine type:*

**$ sudo apt-get install python-pip**

and then type below commands:

**$ sudo apt-get update**

**$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev**

**$ sudo pip install psycopg2**

*Then you will get message like below :*

You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 372kB 1.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.6.1

Comment: On Amazon Linux 2 it is actually `sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

Comment: for python3?? now syas No package libpq-dev available

Answer (score 4):

If you need a more recent version of psycopg2 on your EC2 instance, you can install it directly with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/) using: `$ pip install psycopg2`

You may need to first install the `python-dev` and `libpq-dev` libraries [as explained in this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5450183/845210)