# How to find pg_config path

Tags: python, django, macos, postgresql

Complete newbie here, trying to set up Django to work with PostgreSQL.

I'm using mac osx 10.6.8.  I have also installed PostgreSQL 9.3

When I run `pip install psycopg2` in terminal I get the following error

```
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.5.2.tar.gz (685kB): 685kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/A9/A99cs6x0FNusPejCVkYNTE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_bengorman/psycopg2/setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info

writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



Error: pg_config executable not found.



Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH

or specify the full executable path with the option:



    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...



or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

I've seen a number of posts on this 
[how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python) 
[pg-config-executable-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found)

but I have no clue how to find the bin folder location containing pg_config.  Any tips on finding this path?

Comment: Try `sudo find / -name pg_config` in Terminal.

Comment: As a Mac OS X user please always explain *how you installed PostgreSQL*. There are too many different packages of PostgreSQL for OS X, all with their own bizarre and frustrating quirks. Homebrew? MacPorts? Postgres.app? From source?  EDB? ...

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I recommend that you try to use Postgres.app. (http://postgresapp.com)
This way you can easily turn Postgres on and off on your Mac. 
Once you do, add the path to Postgres to your `.profile` file by appending the following:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"
```

Only after you added Postgres to your path you can try to install `psycopg2` either within a virtual environment (using pip) or into your global site packages.

Comment: This is now in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin`.

Comment: In 9.4 it's here: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config

Comment: Does this mean that with every update I will have to remember to change the version ? Now is 9.5

Comment: If you installed the app as above, file is now in `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_config`on MacOS X 10.11.

Comment: `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"` should work for any latest version.

Comment: Modified the answer to reflect @AidasBendoraitis comment; that will ensure that version changes won't affect functionality.

Comment: As @AidasBendoraitis says, use 'latest' in the path as that is a link to the latest directory and will stop you having to update your path when upgrading Postgres

Comment: Confirming this fix on new Mac/OSX/Catalina. 1Dec2019

Comment: Or simply, to avoid version numbers: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config`

Comment: You saved my life, I spent hours trying to install psycopg2 on a Mac Mini M1 architecture.

Answer (score 52):

```
sudo find / -name "pg_config" -print
```

The answer is /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config in my configuration (MAC Maverick)

Answer (score 38):

Installing homebrew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

And then installing postgresql

```
brew install postgresql
```

gave me this lovely bit of output:

```
checking for pg_config... yes
```

ahhh yeahhhhh

Comment: Just one thing to add, after having  homebrew installed I had to add it to the PATH, using the commands from the installation output message. After that, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 28):

Postgres.app was updated recently. Now it stores all the binaries in "Versions" folder

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH"
```

Where 9.4 – version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted but this is correct - at least for 9.3 and above...

Answer (score 21):

Once you install the current PostgreSQL app on the MacOS X 10.11, this is where the pg_config file is `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_config`.

Then on the Terminal:

```
$ export PG_HOME=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5
$ export PATH=$PATH:$PG_HOME/bin
```

This will put the path in the .profile of whatever terminal you are using.

In your environment (assuming you are using `virtualenv`) you then install psycopg2:

```
$ pip install psycopg2
```

You should see if you had downloaded it before:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... done
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.6.1
```

Comment: Amazing.  In my case it was not under folder library.  It was on /Applications/Postgres.app/.... Big and Many Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To summarize -- PostgreSQL installs its files (including its binary or executable files) in different locations, depending on the version number and the installation method.

Some of the possibilities:

```
/usr/local/bin/
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/
/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/
```

No wonder people get confused!

Also, if your $PATH environment variable includes a path to the directory that includes an executable file (to confirm this, use `echo $PATH` on the command line) then you can run `which pg_config`, `which psql`, etc. to find out [where the file is located](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_%28Unix%29).

Answer (score 8):

### This is how to simply get the path of `pg_config`

```
$ which pg_config                 // prints the directory location 
/usr/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same error, but I installed postgreSQL through brew and re-run the original command and it worked perfectly :

> brew install postgresql

Answer (score 6):

Have same issue on mac, you probably need to

> brew install postgresql

then you can run

> pip install psycopg2

The brew will fix PATH issue for you

this solution works for me at least.

Comment: Works for me in MacOS Catalina version 10.15.5.

Comment: same here worked for me in MacOs Mojave after trying al the above options

Answer (score 4):

You can find the `pg_config` directory using its namesake:

```
$ pg_config --bindir
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin
$
```

Tested on Mac and Debian.  The only wrinkle is that I can't see how to find the bindir for different versions of postgres installed on the same machine.  It's fairly easy to guess though! :-)

Note: I updated my pg_config to 9.5 on Debian with:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5
```

Comment: You have not understood what the problem is. The OP is getting the error because `pg_config` is not among the directories listed in `PATH`. Given this state of fact, then running `pg_config` at the shell like you show won't work *for the exact same reason*.

Comment: True - apologies.  I found this when hunting for paths and skimmed a bit too much!

Comment: Only answer in here that helped me had 0 votes...  All I can provide is one.  In case it helps anyone, brew installs (version 9.5.2) at `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.2/bin`

Answer (score 3):

For people looking for the pg_config path for postgresql installed via **brew** on **Apple silicon**: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql/<postgres_version>/bin`.

For **Intel** based Mac system `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/<postgres_version>/bin` (Need to verify this).

Answer (score 1):

check /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin and you should find pg_config

I.E. `/Library/PostgreSQL/<version_num>/`

ps: you can do the following if you deem it necessary for your pg needs -

create a .profile in your ~ directory

```
export PG_HOME=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3
export PATH=$PATH:$PG_HOME/bin
```

You can now use `psql` or `postgres` commands from the terminal, and install psycopg2 or any other dependency without issues, plus you can always just `ls $PG_HOME/bin` when you feel like peeking at your pg_dir.

Answer (score 1):

I used :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin

pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me by installing the first the following pip packages: `libpq-dev` and `postgresql-common`

Comment: ..question is about finding a folder... you're adding joy about installation of packages...

Answer (score 1):

For those using macOS Big Sur and have their default shell as the Z shell, you can add the path to the py_config binary in the .zprofile which is equivalent to the .bash_profile as explained in this link https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

I had similar issues when using PyCharm with a virtual environment within which I was unable to change my shell to bash to get things going.  Adding the postgres bin path fixed my issue:

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % cat .zprofile
# Setting PATH for Postgres
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Then running this worked without any issues:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

path of pg_config in my case (MacOS)

/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin

Execute the following in the terminal:

```
PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin:$PATH"
```

Then

```
pip install psycopg2
```