# How to install pg gem on rails using postgres.app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have tried all methods listed on other pg topics such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079820/how-to-find-pg-config-path) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162572/error-message-make-sure-that-gem-install-pg-v-0-18-1-succeeds-before-bundl/34095092). All this time I have been able to get away by running `bundle install --without production`. However, this time I need to use a gem that requires pg gem. I need to actually install pg to my machine (OSX El Capitan 10.11.5)

I feel like my best bet is to use suggestion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079820/how-to-find-pg-config-path) to use [postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/). I have tried:

> I recommend that you try to use Postgres.app. (http://postgresapp.com)
>   This way you can easily turn Postgres on and off on your Mac. Once you
>   do, add the path to Postgres to your .profile file by appending the
>   following:
>
> `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"`

and also tried configuring my path on .bash-profile as [said here](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html), but none work.

Another problem I am seeing is, whenever I type command `which_psql` (**edit**: `which psql`)it returns nothing (nothing happens) - is that supposed to happen?

I have tried:

Having on my `.bash_profile`: `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin` and then run gem install pg

Type this on `.profile` `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"` and then run gem install pg.

Did I do anything wrong? I notice that postgres.app can be turned on and off. I have had it on the whole time. Do I have to turn it on before running gem install pg? What is the proper way to install `pg` gem using postgres.app, step by step?

Comment: Try `which psql` and not `which_psql`

Comment: it still does not do anything. I tried running the command on the project folder and home: `which psql`.

Comment: Have you installed `postgresql` locally in your machine?

Comment: Are you using Homebrew? You can install PostgreSQL via Homebrew and it should give you post install instructions about setting it up as a service. This has worked well for me.

Comment: @kcdragon I have RVM. Will it conflict if I use both homebrew and RVM?

Comment: @ArunKumar do I have to install postgresql locally even if I have postgres.app running?

Comment: No, it will not conflict. Homebrew is a general purpose package manager for Mac OSX. RVM is specifically for managing versions of Ruby.

Comment: Cool! I just checked it. It seems like I already have homebrew installed. What is the best way to install postgresql? Also, I don't really know DB very much - do I have to install postgresql once to my machine and that will solve future `pg` installs, or do I have to install postgresql everytime I run new rails app?

Comment: @Iggy No, Looks like postgres.app installs PostgreSQL in your machine. Did you follow the instructions given in http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html ?

Comment: @ArunKumar yes, I followed it. I did the "Configure your $PATH" section; on `~/.bash_profile` I have `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin` saved. Edit: I typed `which psql` again and it showed a path (it didn't before): `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/psql`. Do you know what is the next step?

Comment: @Iggy What do you mean by next step? You have setup a CLI(Command Line Tool) by adding the environmental variable. You can now start the server by clicking on the application in `/Applications` or use CLI to do that. If you close the application, the server will shut down. PS: I have never used postgres.app

Comment: @Iggy, Read [this](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/configuration-ruby.html) to know how to configure the db for rails.