# how to install psycopg2 on Mac (pg_config executable not found error)

Tags: macos, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm learning how to use Postgres with Python (sqlalchemy). I'm stuck when installing `psycopg2`. I have the following error :

`pg_config executable not found error`

I know that's a very common error and there is already a lot of answers about this but I couldn't find anything to help me solve my issue.

I especially don't understand this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079820/how-to-find-pg-config-path) :

> add the path to Postgres to your .profile file by appending the
>   following:
>
> `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"`

What does it mean ? what should I do exactly ?

I also tried to enter `which -a pg_config`in my terminal but nothing happen.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What's unclear about that solution? You need to change the environment variable `PATH` so that `pg_config` can be found.

Comment: should I do this from my terminal ? what should I enter exactly ?

Comment: You could just type this into your terminal: `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"` (if that's indeed the path where `pg_config` is found), then press enter. Then build `psycopg2`.

Comment: when I'm using my mac search bar for "pg_config" I can't find anything. and where doing `which -a pg_config` in my terminal nothing happen.

Comment: Maybe there is a PostgreSQL development package that you didn't install and that contains `pg_config`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I know that ? looking at my application folder I only have Postgres and PSequel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133543/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-laurenz-albe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was solved by typing

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"
```

into the terminal window prior to installing `psycopg2`.