# Trouble with psycopg2 in virtualenv python3 for use with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, virtualenv, psycopg2

I have a Django project that I would like to use with a PostgreSQL database but I am having an issue with psycopg2. When I try to run the dev server or perform a syncdb I get this error. My project is in a virtualenv running Python 3.4 with Django 1.6.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 22, in <module>
    import psycopg2.extensions
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2.extensions'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2.extensions'
```

Which I have taken as I don't have the module installed in the virtualenv which was confirmed with a pip freeze, so I tried to install it using pip but the installer failed and psycopg2, according to pip freeze still wasn't installed. The weird thing was that I could import psycopg2 using the python interpreter but Django just can't see it for some reason and it is not listed in pip. This is where I run into an issue, after running `pip install psycopg2` I get this error message.

```
Creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg

i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.3 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090304 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/include/python3.4m -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement

In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:

./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/build/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-36y2vwa9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/include/site/python3.4 failed with error code 1 in /home/gabriel/DevSpace/Django_Projects/Kevmo/build/psycopg2
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpc3blqa5r
```

I have looked around on SO and some other places and found some people that seem to be having the same problem as me, such as this guy, [How to install psycopg2 with "pip" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python), and everyone seems to say that my issue will be fixed by performing a `apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev` which contain the necessary C components to perform the install. Unfortunately I have these packages already, as well as PostgreSQL and the postgreSQL dev tools so I am not sure what I should do to fix this error. Does anybody know of another way for this error to be caused that isn't missing packages?

Comment: Try `apt-get build-dep psycopg2`

Comment: `apt-get install python-dev` is for Python2, try to install `Python3-dev`

Comment: The python3-dev did it. Thank you! Do you have any idea why I was able to import psycopg2 without having it installed though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve this issue I installed Python3-dev as Leonardo suggested. I was trying to use the python 2 dev tools which obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue using the package "aiopg" which internally installs psycopg2.This package is specially designed for async operations in postgres, but will solve your purpose aswell

```
pip install aiopg
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing this problem while trying to run a Django project with PostgreSQL database running in a virtual environment on Ubuntu 18.04 which was configured under the Windows WSL subsystem.

As suggested in other answers, I too was installing everything for Python2 unknowingly, later I just installed all the required tools for Python3 and it worked.

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib  

sudo apt install libpq-dev

sudo apt install python3-dev

sudo apt install python3-pip

sudo apt install python3-psycopg2

pip3 install psycopg2

pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

Plus, also check if the Ubuntu and Python and Psycopg versions are compatible together.