# Unable to pip install psycopg2 on linux

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip, psycopg2

While trying to create a new Heroku Python (Django) app on Linux Mint I encounter following error when pip tries to install psycopg2

```
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

All dependencies are met (as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python)) so I don't see the problem here..

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python

Comment: Thanks but didn't work .. All dependencies are met..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the solution. It might be helpful for others as I didn't really find the answer online..

1) The error originates from an outdated gcc version (4.8) on my system. This verion does not support the '-fstack-protector-...' command line option.

2) I installed a newer version (4.9) as follows:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
```

3) I removed the symlink x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc which was located in /usr/bin and replaced it with a symlink to the newly installed gcc-4.9 version

```
$ sudo rm x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
$ sudo ln -s gcc-4.9 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
```

It took me a while to figure this out, I hope it helps others

Answer (score 2):

Can't upvote DeBaze's answer (not enough rep).
I'm using Ubuntu 16.02.

I only needed to install the latest gcc and create the symlink ...

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo ln -s gcc-4.9 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
```