# Installation of psycopg2 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, pip

Complete newbie here, trying to set up Django to work with PostgreSQL.
I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and I have also installed PostgreSQL 9.5. 
When I run `pip install psycopg2` in terminal I get the following error:

```
Collecting psycopg2
Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-la8dJp/psycopg2
```

I know that directory containing *pg_config* is `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_config` but I don't know how to add this directory to PATH to get my psycopg2 installed. Or any another method to get psycopg2 installed so that I can interact with my PostgreSQL.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install psycopg2 with "pip" on Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you do have a hard requirement on using the native postgresql library, I would advise you to use the pg8000 library instead because this one is pure python.

Since I discovered it years ago, I stopped using the other one and forgot about the having to compile it on so many platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the help. can i use it with Django and if yes please brief me.

Comment: Actually all the problem was due to old version once i updated to 15.04 problem was solved. Thank you for your help.