# ImportError: No module named psycopg2 virtualenv

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, psycopg2

I realize there are scores of questions around this and I have been through many of them without solving my issue.

Working off of my macbook pro, in pycharm, building a super basic flask app for google app engine, I keep getting the traceback "ImportError: No module named psycopg2" despite having everything in what I believe is order.

Here is link to my really rough main.py file (just started learning flask, etc.) - [link to Gist](https://gist.github.com/psuanm5030/d462a2d771f905dcaf64e93cabe26ee1)

Steps: 
1. When I started building my app, i had a \Lib folder in the app directory where i specifically installed ran

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
```

Included:

- Flask==0.12.2
- Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2
- gunicorn==19.7.1
- psycopg2==2.7.1

Installed without issue and I can see \lib appropriately populated.

Still getting error, so i tried the following:

2. Setting up a virtualenv in my app director from terminal:

   `virtualenv env
   source env/bin/activate
   pip install -r requirements.txt`

Installs nicely into the \env sub-dir.  Still when i run the app locally (and when deployed - although there could be other issues) - I get the following: 
[image: pycharm terminal view]

The reason i am struggling is that it seems to be installed without issue!

EDIT: Link
- [Using Google Cloud SQL Postgres Quickstart (where my data is and documentation i was following)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres)

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Understood.  Part of my intention was to give someone an idea of what I am working with (e.g., imports).  I realize its not all that useful.  thx

Comment: Try easy_install psycopg2

Comment: Also, please see this previous question for more guidance on such issues. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python)