# Cannot access pg_config on virtualenv python

Tags: python-3.x, django, bash, virtualenv

I have a problems when try to install

```
pip install psycopg2
```

the errors is

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

but when I try access pg_config from normal terminal (not in virtualenv mode), I can access the pg_config

Anyone can help ?

[Screenshot of pg_config not found on venv, but found on normal terminal mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1VD8.png)

Comment: How did you create the `virtualenv`?  Where is `pg_config` located? Also you can do `pip install psycopg2-binary` and not involve `pg_config`, with caveats shown [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#quick-install)

Comment: Check if the package is installed in the virtualenv by pip freeze --local or pip list --local.

Comment: Thanks, I can install pyscopg2 with the binary version, but I still don't understand why when use virtualenv, some of bash command can't be accessed
The virtualenv create automaticaly with Pycharm, but when I use python3 -m virtualenv <env_name>, it still can't be accessed

Comment: So, the problems is not with the virtualenv, but with the IDE. I use flatpak version IDE that can't some of bash command, so I switch to non-flatpak, and now is working fine
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install psycopg2 with "pip" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python)