# how can i install psycopg2 in windows 10 when i have error and

Tags: python, django

I have a problem
I cant install with pip install pycopg2
help please [image]
it say could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2

i help pip install psycopg2 but its not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install psycopg2 with "pip" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python)

Comment: no thos not work . i think im must to install some thing befor but i dont now what

Comment: You could try to download package manually from https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/ . And try to setup. I hope it could work