# Psycopg2- wheel fails to build for MacOS

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am using a MacOS and am trying to deploy my web app onto Heroku, but it keeps failing to `build wheel for psycopg2`. I have literally tried everything- I found this article useful: [How to install psycopg2 with "pip" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python)

But even after trying everything the wheel still fails to build.

Here is some of the error message if it helps:

```
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:
         psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:685:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState’ {aka ‘struct _is’}
           685 |     while (interp->next)
               |                  ^~
         error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
         ----------------------------------------
         ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
         Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
       Successfully built alembic blinker dominate Flask-Bootstrap Flask-Mail guess-language-spirit itsdangerous Mako python-editor visitor WTForms
       Failed to build psycopg2
       Installing collected packages: SQLAlchemy, MarkupSafe, Mako, python-editor, six, python-dateutil, alembic, pytz, Babel, blinker, certifi, chardet, click, dnspython, dominate, urllib3, elasticsearch, idna, email-validator, itsdangerous, Jinja2, Werkzeug, Flask, Flask-Babel, visitor, Flask-Bootstrap, Flask-Login, Flask-Mail, Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-Migrate, Flask-Moment, WTForms, Flask-WTF, guess-language-spirit, PyJWT, python-dotenv, requests, psycopg2, gunicorn
           Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
           Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'
           ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
            command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nqnkr57w/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nqnkr57w/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-u2t7aq2l/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/psycopg2
                cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nqnkr57w/psycopg2/

psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:
           psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:685:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState’ {aka ‘struct _is’}
             685 |     while (interp->next)
                 |                  ^~
           error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
           ----------------------------------------
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nqnkr57w/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nqnkr57w/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-u2t7aq2l/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What's your gcc version >> `/usr/bin/gcc -v` ?

Comment: Hi Maurice, it is: Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your platform does not meet the requirements to build it. You can alternatively install the standalone binary

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

You can read more about it here: [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#install-from-source)

Comment: Thanks Jech, I had tried psycopg2-binary. I even uninstalled psycopg2 and only had psycopg2-binary but still have the same problem with the wheel failing to build.

Comment: Can I know what version of psycopg2 you're trying to install as well as your python version? I'm just bouncing ideas here but can you try it with latest version of psycopg2?

Comment: Of course, so psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary are both 2.9.1. (Now I only have the latter installed). My python version is 3.8.8. Do you think it can be a compatibility issue?

Comment: I can't say for sure but there are a lot of build issues for psycopg2 v2.7+python3.8 that's very similar to the one you described but that should be fixed in psycopg2 v2.9. Let me try to repro your issue on heroku.