# django rest framework giving psycopg2 Error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

End developers, I am a FE dev having trouble with setting up BE. I need to connect django project with my FE which uses React.js. I have installed all the required stuff and finally when I ran `make runserver`, it's giving me this error

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

When I ran `make install`, I get another error,

```
~/.poetry/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:152 in _prepare
      148│ 
      149│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      150│ 
      151│             if error is not None:
    → 152│                 raise error from None
      153│ 
      154│             return path
      155│ 
      156│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with psycopg2 (2.9.5) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "psycopg2 (==2.9.5) ; python_version >= "3.6""'.
```

I am using `Macbook Air M2`, if that is related to my specific device.

I am not sure what `psycopg2` is and why I am getting this error. I just simply need my django project to run smoothly so that I can connect to it from FE. Can someone help me debug this issue, big thanks to all of you.

Comment: In your requirements.txt change psycopg2 to psycopg2-binary, then reinstall the requirements that might work

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19711831/11544538) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Postgres as a Database in Development or Production: Psycopg is the most popular PostgreSQL adapter used in  Python hence in Django or Flask etc.

If you have not installed Postgres to your machine, use the following link to install it in your machine:

https://www.postgresql.org/download/

After the installation is completed, and have created the credential to link to  Database.

Use terminal to locate to your Django project and activate virtual environment

then,

`pip3 install psycopg2-binary`

Next in your #settings.py add the following snippet with your credentials

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'ur_db_name',
    'USER': 'ur_user_name',
    'PASSWORD': 'ur_password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Note: You will need to create a database in Postgres, use the name of the database you created in as <ur_db_name>

That's it, this will connect to your database, and you can use any frontend framework of your choice to build your app

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to Poetry and not to psycopg2 specifically. Check the recent [issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7611) that was created for Poetry 1.4.0. I can confirm that downgrading Poetry to 1.3.2 solves the problem of intermittent errors like this.